# How Can I create jsonpath to get first part of json?

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to create a jsonpath to take first part of whole json. I have trouble because I dont have any key for sub jsons.

For Example, I have this json;

```html
[
  [
    "name",
    "surname",
    "age"
],
  [
    {
      "X": "Mike",
      "Y": "Tyson"
    },
    {
      "X": "Irina",
      "Y": "Shat"
    }
  ]
]
```

I want to divide this json to 2 different json;

```html
 [
    "name",
    "surname",
    "age"
]
```

```html
[
    {
      "X": "Mike",
      "Y": "Tyson"
    },
    {
      "X": "Irina",
      "Y": "Shat"
    }
  ]
```

I try to use index but doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work? Give a [mcve].

Comment: I try to take first json part on https://jsonpath.com/ to appy on java code

Comment: I mean actual code, not a vague description.

Comment: Did you try $[0]

Comment: You can simply get it by the index `0`, `1` and so on. `[...][0]` and `[...][1]`

Comment: $[0] it works thank you @JuanMendes